# Rails Devise Gem, (undefined method `to_datetime' for nil:NilClass) when i want to recover a password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, passwords, reset

i'm having troubles with Devise Gem, i'm using the default recoverable methods, the links is being sent. The reset values (reset_password_sent_at) is saved in the database, but when i have to write down the new password and update it, gives this error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_datetime' for nil:NilClass):
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/date_time/calculations.rb:161:in `<=>'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:286:in `compare_with_coercion'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb:214:in `<=>'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:97:in `=='
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:97:in `!='
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:97:in `_field_changed?'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:66:in `write_attribute'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:39:in `reset_password_sent_at='
  devise (3.5.6) lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:94:in `clear_reset_password_token'
  devise (3.5.6) lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:32:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Recoverable>'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:377:in `_run__1626105923374900797__update__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:310:in `update_record'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:70:in `update_record'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:477:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:393:in `_run__1626105923374900797__save__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:106:in `save'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:32:in `save'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block in save'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:281:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:269:in `save'
  devise (3.5.6) lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:48:in `reset_password'
  devise (3.5.6) lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:141:in `reset_password_by_token'
  devise (3.5.6) app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb:32:in `update'
```

debugging this its seems to be a problem with the reset_password_sent_at being nil when the password is reset (lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb:94:inclear_reset_password_token)

I've try to change my local time to the UTC stored but the problem isn't that. Any suggestion?

Comment: When you use the default devise methods than you dont have to change the existing code of devise.

Comment: If you are using gem "letter_opener" than password reset email won't actually being sent

Comment: i'm not using letter_opener. The mail is being sent.

Also i'm using the default methods, so i don't override or change the code of devise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution for this was to upgrade my rails from 4.0.2 to 4.2.7. When i run the bundle install and update the gemfile dependencies now is working.

Upgrading devise from (3.5.6) to (4.2.0)